# Use DATEDIFF in a case

Tags: case, sqlplus, datediff

I got a problem with my request.

I want to compare 2 dates, and if the number of days is inferior to 2, i want to display nothing. But if it's over, I want to display the days.
I got my request but it failed when I try to compare the DATEDIFF to 2.

```
SQL> SELECT noLivraison, noCommande, noArticle, dateCommande, quantite, dateLivraison, quantiteLivree, 
CASE dateCommande
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, dateLivraison, dateCommande) < 2 THEN null
ELSE DATEDIFF(day, dateLivraison, dateCommande)
END nombreJoursEcoules
FROM Commande
NATURAL JOIN LigneCommande
NATURAL JOIN Livraison      
NATURAL JOIN DetailLivraison  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  
 10  /
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, dateLivraison, dateCommande) < 2 THEN null
                                                *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

I don't know how to fix it, I put more parenthesis but it didn't works.

Ty for reading.

Comment: If that's all of your query, you are missing an `end` keyword after `then null` probably.

Comment: There is no `datediff()` function in Oracle.

Comment: So what's the function to get the number of days between two dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code , may be it will solve your problem

```
         select col1,col2,case when DATEDIFF(dd, dateLivraison, dateCommande)

         >= 2 then 'days' else null end as 'datefield', DATEDIFF(dd, dateLivraison, 

         dateCommande) as 'days' from tablename
```

Thanks